# Individual Azure file share usage alerts and graphs

Tags: azure

Within an Azure File Share I can graph high level metrics like average file count, average quota size etc (see the screenshot below), but there is no way to select individual shares.

The open user voice suggestion at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/34491502-alerts-for-reaching-file-share-quota-limit is asking for alerts (so I assume this is not available), but is there any way to graph these individual share metrics?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's impossible.

After you add a metrics "File Share quote size", then click the "Add filter" button -> in the `Values` drop-down menu, there is only All but no individual for each file share.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the file share capacity metric for standard file share
is currently available at the storage account level and not per-share.
What this means is, if you want to create an alert for a file share
with the standard storage account, then you have to create one file share per standard
storage account, otherwise you have to use the premium File Storage account.

The Per-share capacity metric is currently only available for premium file shares.
So when you create the condition for the alert with a premium account,
you will see all the file shares created under that account.
However with standard storage account, you will see ANY instead of a particular file share.